# 90's book series about a boy controlling spaceship with his mind

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

In what I think was the first book, a boy (and maybe a girl?) control a space ship with their minds. They are in a vast room with bowl-like depressions in the ground that they stand in to control the ship. In another book a girl is in a coma in our world, but she is living her life in another reality also. There was also a part in one book where a kid disappeared while in a tunnel on a roller coaster.

That's all I can remember. Can anyone identify the series?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like Anne McCaffrey's 'The Ship Who Sang'.  This novel has the concept of a severely physically disabled girl who's brain is transplanted into a space-ship.

I don't recall any bowl-like depressions in the book - but I read this about 25-years ago...

Note that this novel was originally a set of several short stories.

Comment: I actually thought of her Pegasus books...  I don't think either series is a particularly good fit though, honestly.  Yours involves children who would otherwise have died being encased in titanium bubbles to live as spaceships (or cities or whatnot) and mine involves kids (initially) throwing spaceships around the galaxy using psychic powers.